# OOP Method overriding

Tags: php, oop, overriding

Is there a way to get the return value of the foo method in the parent class? In the code below I get "b" my goal is to get "a" without changing the method names and without using `return (new a () -> foo ());`

```
interface i {
      function foo();
    }

    class a implements i {
      public function foo() {
        return 'a';
      }

      public function foo1() {
       // return (new a()->foo()); 
        return $this->foo();
      }
    }

    class b extends a  {
      public function get() {
        return parent::foo1();
      }

      public function foo() {
        return 'b';
      }
    }

    $b=new b();
    $b->get(); //return b
```

Update: the goal is to have access to foo method in the parent class from another third class for example

```
    class c {
      public function __construct(i $b)
  {
    $this->b = $b;
  }

public function get() {
  $this->b->foo1();
}
    }
```

Comment: `return self::foo();` in `public function foo1() {`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure - just as @arkascha - what the actual goal is. Here is another possibility what might be meant (with explicitly going via a method foo1):

```
<?php

interface i {
  function foo();
}

class a implements i {
  public function foo() {
    return 'a';
  }

  public function foo1() {
   // here the 'self' is the trick instead of $this (and the only change to your code)
      return self::foo();
  }
}

class b extends a  {
  public function get() {
    return parent::foo1();
  }

  public function foo() {
      return parent::foo();
  }
}

$b=new b();
echo $b->get(); //returns a
```

Answer (score 0):

You ask if it is possible to get the return value of `a::foo()`, so 'a', by calling a method of an object of type `b`. That should be pretty straight forward, unless I completely miss understood what you are trying to do:

```
<?php
interface i {
    function foo();
}

class a implements i {
    public function foo() {
        return 'a';
    }
}

class b extends a {
    public function get() {
        return parent::foo();
    }

    public function foo() {
        return 'b';
    }

}

$b = new b;
echo $b->get(); // obviously returns 'a'
```

This is because you *explicitly* call `parent::foo()` which obviously resolves to `a::foo()`.

Answer (score 0):

instead of calling a

```
public function get() {
    return parent::foo1();
}
```

call the method foo using the parent like this

```
public function get() {
    return parent::foo();
}
```

and you will get the a as a result

Answer (score 0):

call `parent::foo()` inside your subclass to have direct access to parent foo() method!